Failed building rpms for nvidia drivers using fedora
I tried to install nvidia drivers on my fedora 40 using the rpmfusion repositories
sudo akmods --force
but I got the following error
Checking kmods exist for 6.10.4-200.fc40.x86_64 [  OK  ]
Building and installing nvidia-kmod [FAILED]
Building rpms failed; see /var/cache/akmods/nvidia/550.67-1-for-6.10.4-200.fc40.x86_64.failed.log for details

Hint: Some kmods were ignored or failed to build or install.
You can try to rebuild and install them by by calling
'/usr/sbin/akmods --force' as root.

and on checking the above mentioned log file, I saw
THE ERROR LOG FILE
Ofcourse I expected it to build normally. I would really appreciate your guidance if any of you ever happened to stumble upon this or have any idea of what the underlying reasons could be.

please don't be bothered by why 550 and not 555, I first tried on 555,
but it had the same result, so I thought maybe there could be
something if I just downgraded

